# Destroy and Show have same url in RoR, is it good?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

Is it good when url to show and destroy are same? How it can be changed in RoR if i want continue use standard tools like *script/generate scaffold* ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are following the REST convention Rails recommends, the url of a resource (noun) would be /resource_name/id for view, delete, update, and the difference will be the HTTP method (verb) you issue to the server: GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE.

Comment: In Rails terminology, "edit" is "show the form to edit this resource," whereas "update" is "submit changes to this resource." "edit" generally only makes sense in the context of HTML. This same distinction is true for "new" versus "create."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is good. Rails use the URL as well as the HTTP verb (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to determine which action a request should resolve to. `script/generate scaffold` has this behaviour, so you can continue to use it.

Comment: Hm.. Are RoR use DELETE instead of POST in real life?

Comment: No, RoR uses POST in real life with a trick: It will automagically add a parameter to the post:   _method=delete 
This is not so well documented, IMHO. Here's a lecture note about it:
http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/rails/howtos/rest/handout.pdf